# Add gif above image

Tags: android, image, gif

I have an ImageView that has an Image in it. I want to add an animated gif above that image. Any idea how? Should I create a surfaceView below the ImageView and the gif? Or is there something else?

Comment: Look into using a Frame layout - it allows you to have one view hover over another, probably good enough for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `FrameLayout` allows you to stack layouts on top of each other.

You might try something like this:

```
<FrameLayout...>
    <ImageView...
        src="yourImage.png"
    />

    <WebView...
        id="@+id/your_web_view"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Unfortunately, `ImageView` does not animate GIFs, so you can use a `WebView` to load the GIF.

You can do this programatically:

```
WebView gifView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_web_view);
gifView.loadUrl("file:///path/to/your.gif")
```

You should double check which way it stacks, but IIRK every element is on top of the element before it, unless otherwise specified.

**NOTE:** I excluded all the required Android tags like `layout_width`, `layout_height`, etc. from the example above for simplicity. You will have to add those.

Comment: Everything is ok except one thing.. Its not moving.. :P

Comment: @AllieFly Updated! You have to use a `WebView` to load the GIF so that it animates (if you want to do it natively). Otherwise, I am sure there are tons of libraries that can display GIFs as well.